# How do I get the ball to stop when it hits the ground?

Tags: plotting

1) I would like the graph to stop when the ball hits the ground (y=o). I have declared xmax, but have not been able to incorporate it into my code.

2) I would also like to include animate, where for a given initial velocity and angle, one could hit a button that would show the flight of the ball.

3) I would like for the trajectory to appear only when the animate button is hit.

```
    f[t_, v_, a_] := v*Cos[a Degree]*t
    g[t_, v_, a_] := v*Sin[a Degree]*t - (9.82*t^2)/2
    c[t_, v_, a_] := {f[t, v, a], g[t, v, a]}
    xmax[v_, a_] := (v^2*Sin[2*a])/9.8     (*x value when ball hits ground*)
    ymax[v_, a_] := (v^2*(Sin^2)[a])/19.6  (*maximum height*)
    tmax[v_, a_] := (v*Sin[a Degree]/4.9)  (*time when ball hits ground*) 

    Manipulate[
     Show[
      ParametricPlot[
       {f[t, v, a], g[t, v, a]}, {t, 0, 10},
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}
             ],(*close parametric plot*)
      ListPlot[{c[t, v, a]},
       PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[.025]}
             ],(*close list plot*)
      PlotRange -> {{0, 300}, {0, 200}},
      ImageSize -> Full,
      AspectRatio -> Automatic,
      AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
      AxesLabel -> {"x(t)","y(t)"}
             ],(*close show*)
     {{t, .00001, "Elapsed Time (seconds)"}, .00001, 10, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{v, 50, "Initial velocity (m/s)"}, 1, 50, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     {{a, 45, "Initial angle (degrees)"}, 1, 89, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
     Delimiter, SaveDefinitions -> True
             ](*close manipulate*)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you fill it with rice (raw or cooked) it might still bounce but not very high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have made a small change to address the issue of ball stopping when it hits the ground. Let me know if this is what you want. Have not looked at the others.

```
  Manipulate[
     Show[ParametricPlot[{f[t, v, a], Max[g[t, v, a], 0]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
         ListPlot[{c[t, v, a]}, PlotStyle -> {Black, PointSize[0.025]}], 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 300}, {0, 200}}, ImageSize -> Full, 
         AspectRatio -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
      AxesLabel -> {"x(t)", "y(t)"}], {{t, 0.00001, 
       "Elapsed Time (seconds)"}, 0.00001, 10, 
         Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{v, 50, "Initial velocity (m/s)"}, 1, 
      50, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
       {{a, 45, "Initial angle (degrees)"}, 1, 89, 
      Appearance -> "Labeled"}, Delimiter, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: That was perfect!  The line no longer goes below 0.  I modified the code so the ball would follow the line as well. The only button I want to animate is the Elapsed Time.  I will work on that again.